# Get data form a sim card via a smart card reader

Tags: c, pcsc

I' trying to get it using a SmartCard reader with the communication protocol PC/SC and CCID.

I send some bytes to the smartcard reader via the function sCardTransmit. The answer I get back is 61 2E. The documentation said that this means some data is available to read. But how can I read out the data with the functions from the library? Does this function will work SCardGetAttrib()? I thought I get the data back with the Transmit function.

Thanks for help,

Florian

Comment: What is your target platform?

Comment: my target platform is a linux ubuntu.